# Trying to apply the "width" inline style property to a span tage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having the following issue: I am trying to space each of the values underneath each of the title header (see image) in Bootstrap 4.  They are currently set up as  tags because we are inside of an accordion.   I tried the following approach, but that did not work:

`<span style="width: pecentagenumber%">NUMBER</span>`

How can I do this?

My current code:

```
 <div id="accordion>
        <h3>
          <span>@bill.MonthName, @bill.Year</span>
          <span>@bill.PackageCount</span>
          <span>Tier @bill.Tier</span>
          <span>$@bill.TotalPrice</span>
          <span>UNPAID</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
```

This is how it looks currently. 
[image]

Comment: A span is a `display: inline` element, which can't have a width set. You can use a display:block element instead (like a `<div>`) or use CSS to set the style of those spans to `display: block` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a flexible ability to edit you HTML - lets use bootstrap 4 `row` and `cols` structure.

```
<div id="accordion" class="container">
  <h3 class="row">
    <span class="col">@bill.MonthName, @bill.Year</span>
    <span class="col">@bill.PackageCount</span>
    <span class="col">Tier @bill.Tier</span>
    <span class="col">$@bill.TotalPrice</span>
    <span class="col">UNPAID</span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

This way you will get 5 cols with the same width. It's better to use `div` instead `h3` and `span`, but I tried adapt it to your request.

More about [BS4 Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)